# How to minify Magento 1.x core JS/CSS files?

Tags: magento-1, minify

Any ways how to minify core JS/CSS files in Magento 1.x? (Prototype.js, etc) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this extension

https://www.apptrian.com/minify-html-css-js-for-magento

Worked really well for me.

Best of all - it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like prototype and jquery are available minified anyway. For other stuff I use Fishpig's Minify... https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/minify/

It's not free but it works really well and the support is excellent.